# Are there open source app/programs to turn backlight on and off in Elementary os?

Tags: asus, release-hera, backlight

I use **elementary OS 5.1 Hera**. In particular, I am using **Asus ROG Strix G Core i5 G531GT-BQ002T
Gaming Laptop**   and can't find command for the Keyboard backlight let alone RGB strip. There is no key for it on my device. If anyone is interested then plz work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. Here is the [link](https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore) to the github repository of the project **rogauracore** by **wroberts**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to understand what you are getting at. Regardless, if you want an application to lower your screen brightness below your pc's absolute minimum, then use [this](https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/brightness-controller.html) screen brightness-controller. Yes, it's open-source.

Comment: I was referring to the backlit Keyboard and the surrounding RGB strip of an [Asus ROG laptop](https://images.app.goo.gl/ebW7A6aHNoqZGuLj8)